# django security- how to prevent many POSTs?

Tags: django, forms, security, post, brute-force

In my tests, I could create many POSTs to my server and thus brute-force forms like login. But not only, as my question is for any form, even for logged in user I don't want anyone to be able to POST so much times in short time.
What can be done in django? I could not find a good info in the docs (have read Security in Django').
What can be done in django to prevent multiple form submissions, or limit them per IP/session ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this third-lib [django-throttle-requests](https://github.com/sobotklp/django-throttle-requests)

It allows you to specify rules in order to set a rate limit for request in Django.